# MySQL search per char

Tags: mysql

I have a table, look like this
[image]

and I want to query the table for looking that `GROUP_CONCAT(product_id SEPARATOR ', ')` field have `7` and `10`.

`Like` statement is not working well for me because it's only showing the first row and not showing the third row, even it has `7` and `10` but separated with `8` between it..

[image]

Is there's any `WHERE STATEMENT` that I can use for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should be troubled ?

Try this

```
SELECT * from table where field REGEXP 'abdan|copin|sher';
```

Comment: what does `'abdan|copin|sher'` mean?

Comment: It was the object of the name that u want to find

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a `where` clause, you want a `having` clause:

```
having sum(product_id = 7) > 0 and
       sum(product_id = 10) > 0
```

Comment: it's giving me an empty set... here's my sql that I run with your `having` sugestion `select * from (SELECT purchase_order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(product_id SEPARATOR ', ') as product_ordered from ufi_purchaseorderdetail GROUP BY purchase_order_id) as a having sum(product_ordered = 7) > 0 and sum(product_ordered = 10) > 0;`

Comment: did you mean `product_ordered` ? because I trying to search on product_ordered field (please look at the second picture)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like `'7%10'` for this case. But if the string sequence is `10, 8, 7`, you have to include `'10%7'` in the query. I faced with similar case with you before, but I didn't store the data in your way.

This is a `ManyToMany` association, so you can store the `group_contact` in another table `group(id int primary key, group int not null)`. Then use a third table `middle_table(order_id int, group_id int)` to map them. Hope this help for you.